# Display my .NET Standard assembly in the Add Reference dialog for a UWP application

Tags: c#, .net, uwp

I am trying to figure out how to display my .NET Standard assembly in the Visual Studio Reference Manager under Assemblies/Extensions for a UWP application.

I currently do this with a .NET Framework assembly for .NET Framework applications by setting the proper registry key (from the Microsoft docs [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-add-or-remove-references-by-using-the-reference-manager)):

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft.NETFramework\\AssemblyFoldersEx\MyAssemblies]@=""

This works great for .NET Framework, but I cannot figure out how to do the same thing for my .NET Standard 2.0 assembly and UWP applications.

For example, with the above registry addition and a .NET Framework project, my .NET Framework assembly is automatically shown in the Reference Manager dialog under Assemblies/Extensions.  In addition, projects that have a reference to the assembly know where it is located.

I can't seem to do this with a .NET Standard 2.0 assembly and a UWP project.  The registry entry appears to be only for .NET Framework assemblies, not assemblies used with UWP.  Part of the registry key is the lowest version of the .NET Framework my assembly supports.  For example:
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft.NETFramework\v2.0.50727\AssemblyFoldersEx\My Assembly\

I tried creating a registry key with the .NET Framework version 4.6.1 and my .NET Standard assembly does show up in the Reference Manager for projects targeting .NET Framework 4.6.1 or newer, but it still does not show up in Reference Manager for UWP projects.  I have to manually browse to the assembly file.

Is there a way to have the .NET Standard 2.0 assembly automatically show in Reference Manager for UWP projects like I am able to do for the .NET Framework assembly?

Comment: .NET Standard assemblies might be shipped as NuGet packages, so that consumers can resolve all necessary dependencies. It is counter intuitive to use raw assemblies for UWP/.NET Core based projects nowadays.

Comment: Thanks for clarification. Maybe ask the [.NET folks on GitHub](https://github.com/dotnet/standard/issues)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reached out on GitHub as Peter suggested, and I'm including the answer below.

> Adding references using that registry key will only work on .NET
>   Framework. UWP works more like .NET Core, and the runtime won't really
>   even find the assemblies if they are not properly located either in
>   the application folder, or in a location specified in the deps.json
>   file that gets generated as part of the build.
>
> Furthermore, a .NET Standard assembly might have different
>   dependencies depending on which consuming app is trying to reference
>   it (for example, you may get different dependencies if you try to load
>   it from a .NET Core executable than if you are trying to load it from
>   a .NET Framework executable, or UWP one). For these reasons, the
>   suggested way to add a reference to a .NET Standard library from a UWP
>   app is to either add a Project to Project reference, or to depend on
>   it via a NuGet Package. This will ensure that the right dependencies
>   get deployed along with your UWP app.

Answer (score 0):

.NET Standard 2.0 assemblies should appear by default as long as your app has a minimum target of 1709 (build 16299 aka "RS3") or higher ([source](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/announcing-uwp-support-for-net-standard-2-0/)).

If your min-version is lower than that, you can only use .NET Standard 1.4 ([source](https://github.com/dotnet/standard/blob/master/docs/versions/netstandard1.4.md)).

Comment: I don't think I was clear enough in my question, and I have edited it with additional information.